# Android UI freezes when doing firebase firestore read and write?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-activity

I have app which does live streaming. I have a method to upload data to firebase every 1 minute. During this operation activity UI freezes for couple of seconds. This happens every time I call the firebase upload method. Also, it is not happening immediately, it happens after streaming for more than a hour.

I tried using Thread, Executors, async, threadpool, etc. But, nothing solves the issue

```
public void dropDeviceInfo(String streamId, String streamState, Boolean fromForceStart, Context context, boolean isMuted, boolean isAutoFocus, boolean adaptiveBitrateEnabled, int currentResolutionTarget, StreamQuality targetStreamQuality, boolean isDropInitialBandwithAlerts, String bandwidthMessage, String alertType, boolean shouldAddConnectivityBW, boolean shouldAddDeviceDetail, boolean shouldAddAFInfo, boolean shouldAddAudioInfo, boolean shouldDropNetWorkSource) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Map<String, Object> deviceInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    db.collection("livestreamTechnicals").document(streamId).collection("deviceInfo").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        Log.e("is success", task.isSuccessful() + "");
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                try {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        documentId = document.getId();
                    }
                    DocumentReference reference = db.collection("livestreamTechnicals").document(streamId).collection("deviceInfo").document(documentId);
                    Log.d("deviceInfo", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0).getData());
                    Map<String, Object> netSource = new HashMap<>();
                    netSource.put("networkSource", getNetworkClass(context));
                    netSource.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date()));
                    reference.update("connectionInfo", FieldValue.arrayUnion(netSource));

                    Map<String, Object> bwAlerts = new HashMap<>();
                    bwAlerts.put("message", bandwidthMessage);
                    bwAlerts.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date()));
                    reference.update("bandwidthAlerts", FieldValue.arrayUnion(bwAlerts));

                    reference.update("streamState", streamState);

                    if (shouldAddAudioInfo) {
                        Map<String, Object> audioDetails = new HashMap<>();
                        if (isMuted)
                            audioDetails.put("message", "Audio is now turned off");
                        else
                            audioDetails.put("message", "Audio is now turned on");
                        audioDetails.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date()));
                        reference.update("streamAudioInfo", FieldValue.arrayUnion(audioDetails));
                    }

                    if (shouldAddAFInfo) {
                        Map<String, Object> autoFocusDetails = new HashMap<>();
                        if (isAutoFocus)
                            autoFocusDetails.put("message", "Autofocus - ON");
                        else
                            autoFocusDetails.put("message", "Autofocus - OFF");

                        autoFocusDetails.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date()));
                        reference.update("focusInfo", FieldValue.arrayUnion(autoFocusDetails));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Firebase SDKs perform all network and file I/O off the main thread already. So if something is blocking rendering, that is likely some of your own code (for example some pre- or post-processing of the data). It's impossible for us to say what that is based on the code you shared though - so I recommend running in a profiler or adding logging to see where the app is spending its time.

Comment: If I commented the above code it is working fine